# Automatically scroll to newly added row in datagridview MVVM light

Tags: silverlight, mvvm-light

*** SOLVED ***
I finally solved it 'Dirty' in the code behind, could've been cleaner & nicer MVVM though
the observable collection stuff is still done in the ViewModel...

```
    public ViewModelLocator VML = new ViewModel.ViewModelLocator();

    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        VML.MainMatch.Add();
            dataGrid.SelectedIndex = VML.MainMatch.Matches.Count - 1;
           dataGrid.ScrollIntoView(VML.MainMatch.Matches, dataGrid.Columns[0]);
    }
```

---

I have a view with a datagrid and a button hooked up to a relaycommand to add records to the observable collection (datagrid's itemsource), the following works fine:

View:

```
<Button x:Name="btnAdd" Content="{Binding Resource.btnAdd, Source={StaticResource CustomLocStrings}}" Width="100" Command="{Binding AddCommand, Mode=OneWay}" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  IsEnabled="{Binding IsLimitedUser, Converter={StaticResource TrueToFalseConverter}}"/>
```

ViewModel:

```
    AddCommand = new RelayCommand(() => Add());

    private void Add()
    {
       game _game = new game();
       _game.recid = 1;
       _game.teamid = GlobalVariables.CurrentUser.teamid;

       if (this.games != null)
       {
           this.games.Add(new gameViewModel(_game));
       }
       else
       {
            var _games = new List<gameViewModel>();
            _games.Add(new gameViewModel(_game));
            this.games = new ObservableCollection<gameViewModel>(_gamees);
       }
```

The problem is that the row is added at the bottom of the datagrid, outside the users view.
He has to scroll down to see the new record.
What I want is that the grid automatically does a scrollintoview to the new record.

I've found a similar issue here (http://forums.lhotka.net/forums/p/9086/43212.aspx): but failed to translate it to my situation:

I tried it with EventTocCommand

```
     <i:Interaction.Triggers>
     <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
      <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Path=AddCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=dataGrid}"/>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
```

And then

```
    RelayCommand<EventArgs> AddCommand = new RelayCommand<EventArgs>(Add);
```

but nothing happens when I click, I suspect my commandparameter's wrong..

I hope someone has a solution since my user interface is not really 'user friendly' the way it is..

Thanks in advance,

Mike

Answer (score 0):

I havent tried it, but i think setting the SelectedItem is going to be worth a try.

SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"

So, create your object, add it to the grid, and set the SelectedItem to the same (new) object.

Comment: thnx but it doesn't seem to respond when I set the selectedgame.. Maybe I'll just do it in the View's code behind..